# Typescript: Constraint on a field of an union type

Tags: typescript, types, constraints, field, union

I created a **union type of objects**. They all have a field `role` to differentiate them.
Here we have **teacher** and **student**:

```js
type User =
    {
        role: "student";
        followClasses: string[];
    } |
    {
        role: "teacher";
        since: number;
    };
```

Then I wanted to create a function to generate a **default student**:

```js
const defaultStudent = (): User => ({
    role: "student",
    followClasses: [],
});
```

But since the **return type** is the union type **User**, typescript **doesn't know that it's a student**, and **throw me a warning** when I type this:

```js
const student = defaultStudent();

console.log(student.followClasses);
//          Warning here ⮥
```

How to make the function `defaultStudent` have a constrained return type (student)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the two members of the unions as individual types

```js
type Student = {
  role: "student"
  followClasses: string[]
}

type Teacher = {
  role: "teacher"
  since: number
}
```

and define your union from them directly

```js
type User = Student | Teacher
```

At this point, you can say that your `defaultStudent` function doesn't just return a `User`, you can be more precise than that. It returns a `Student`.

```js
const defaultStudent = (): Student => ({
  role: "student",
  followClasses: [],
})

const student = defaultStudent()
console.log(student.followClasses) // <-- OK
```